# Play smooth streaming files on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I would like to be able to play smooth streaming files (ismv, ism, ismc) locally on my Ubuntu PC to make sure my video encoder is working properly.

Is there some Ubuntu package that can play ismv, ism, ismc files?

I searched on Google without success.

Answer (score 2):

`.ismv` is the actual video extension. `.ism` is the server's manifest, and `.ismc` is the client's manifest to keep track of the fragmented parts in the `.ismv` file.

Instead of playing them natively, which I don't think any Ubuntu players support, you can convert them. Try [MP4Split](http://www.unified-streaming.com/support/documentation/mp4split-documentation/).

The basic command would be:

```
mp4split -o output.mp4 input.ismv
```